# Is the following inductive argument valid for establishing the relationship between two recurrence relations?

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

Is the following inductive argument valid?

**Let:**

- $x$ be a positive real
- $n,t \ge 1$ be an integers
- $p_n$ be the $n$th prime
- $p\#$ be the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) of $p$
- gcd$(a,b)$ is the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of $a$ and $b$
- $H_n(x)$ be the count of integer $i$ such that $0 < i \le x$ and gcd$(i,p_n\#)=1$
- $x \% t$ be the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) such that if $c = x \% t$, then $\lfloor x\rfloor \equiv c \pmod t$ and $0 \le c < t$
- $c_n(x)$ be [recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) defined as follows:

> - $c_0(x) = \dfrac{x \% t}{t}$
> - $c_n(x) = c_{n-1}(x) - c_{n-1}\left(\dfrac{x}{p_{n}}\right)$

**Observation:**

- $H_n(x)$ can be defined as a recurrence relation:

> - $H_0(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$
> - $H_n(x) = H_{n-1}(x) - H_{n-1}\left(\frac{x}{p_{n}}\right)$

**Inductive Argment to be evaluated:**

For any given positive integer $t$:
$$\frac{H_n(x)}{t} = H_n\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) + c_n(x)$$

(1) Base Case $n=0$

- $\dfrac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{t} - \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor \% t}{t} = \left\lfloor\dfrac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{t}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{t}\right\rfloor$
- $\dfrac{H_0(x)}{t} = \dfrac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{t}= \left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{t}\right\rfloor + \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor \% t}{t} = H_0\left(\dfrac{x}{t}\right) + c_0(x)$

(2) Assume up to $n\ge0$:

- $\dfrac{H_n(x)}{t} = H_n\left(\dfrac{x}{t}\right) + c_n(x)$

(3) Inductive Step:

- $\dfrac{H_{n+1}(x)}{t} = \dfrac{H_{n}(x) - H_{n}\left(\frac{x}{p_{n+1}}\right)}{t} = H_n\left(\dfrac{x}{t}\right) + c_n(x) - H_n\left(\dfrac{\frac{x}{p_{n+1}}}{t}\right) - c_n\left(\dfrac{x}{p_{n+1}}\right) = H_{n+1}\left(\dfrac{x}{t}\right) + c_{n+1}(x)$

Comment: I just deleted my comment because I was focusing only on the inductive argument part. I just realized you originally defined "$H_n(x)$ be the count of integer $i$ such that $0 < i \le x$ and gcd$(i,p_n\#)=1$". I didn't check whether or not your recurrence relation for $H_n(x)$ actually works for your original definition. If it does, then everything then seems correct to me.

Comment: Thanks.  I am pretty confident that $H_n(x)$ works as claimed.  That one has been checked many times in other questions on this site.  :-)   My question is pretty much assuming that the recurrence relations are validly defined, does induction establish the conclusion.  Thanks very much for feedback on the inductive argument!  :-)

Comment: You're welcome. I've looked at your definition more closely now and I agree $H_n(x)$ should work as claimed. I just wanted to try to make sure I wasn't missing anything when I stated that what you did seemed to be correct to me. Also, note I also don't see anything offhand which I can suggest to you to change or improve on.